# IsDeleted does not exist in context but it is defined in the class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, null

I've been stuck at this error for a really long time and I can't figure out why I'm getting it? IsDeleted is defined in my class, just like Department. But it says IsDeleted doesn't exist.

Also, is there another way to return staffs WHERE IsDeleted is either false or null? It doesn't allow me to do that. It's a boolean value but it is a nullable value as well. I only want to display staffs where IsDeleted is equals to false or null.

**Problematic code**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{  
    var staffs = db.Staffs.Include(s => s.Department).ToList();

    return View(staffs.Where(IsDeleted = false));
}
```

**Error**

> The name 'IsDeleted' does not exist in the current context

**Staff Class**

```
public partial class Staff
{
    [Display(Name = "Staff ID")]
    public int StaffID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department ID")]
    public Nullable<int> DeptID { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code looks for a variable in scope named `IsDeleted`. It is not an expression that will be used to evaluate each record.

In order to do the latter, you need a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
staffs.Where(s => !s.IsDeleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

it shoud be this below

```
return View(staffs.Where(x=> !x.IsDeleted));
```

or if you prefer

```
return View(staffs.Where(x=> x.IsDeleted == false));
```